# Apply registry tweak to newly created users

Tags: windows, windows-registry

Assume I have made "This PC" show up on my desktop with this registry tweak:

```
[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\HideDesktopIcons\NewStartPanel]
"{20D04FE0-3AEA-1069-A2D8-08002B30309D}"=dword:00000000
```

And now I want to make this a kind of "system default" that applies to all users that's created after my modification, while leaving existing users unaffected. How can I achieve that?

I have looked at `HKEY_USER\.DEFAULT` but that looks a bit strange and I'm afraid it's not the right place to apply my tweaks.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

#### How can I apply a registry tweak to new users?

You need to apply your tweak to `HKEY_USERS` in `%SystemDrive%\Users\Default\NTUSER.DAT`. This has to be done by loading the registry hive.

Any settings changed in the loaded hive will be copied to every new user profile that is created.

Full instructions below.

Note:

- For Domain Users this would done using Group Policy. See [Deploying Custom Registry Changes through Group Policy](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/askds/2007/08/14/deploying-custom-registry-changes-through-group-policy/)

> To make sure every new profile created on a machine gets specific user
> settings we will need to change the registry settings that are used to
> build all new profiles. The trick is first to understand where these
> default settings come from. Then when we know where they come from we
> need to be able to edit them and save them. Once that is done all new
> profiles will be created with whatever settings we want.
>
> The location of where new profiles copy their user registry settings
> is located on the file system at
> `%SystemDrive%\Users\Default\NTUSER.DAT` in Windows 7 and Windows
> Vista, in Windows XP it is located at `%SystemDrive%\Documents` and
> `Settings\Default User\NTUSER.DAT`. Now that we know what file is
> copied to create all new profile user registry settings we just need a
> way to edit the settings. Well there’s a tool for that, it’s called
> `Regedit.exe`.
>
> The trick with editing the default user profile registry settings is
> to first know that it is not available in `Regedit.exe` by default. We
> will need to load the `NTUSER.DAT` file into `Regedit.exe` to be able
> to edit the settings. Open `Regedit.exe` by going to Start and typing
> `Regedit`, then right-click the search result and select Run as
> administrator. If you are currently logged on with a non-administrator
> the User Account Control box will allow you to provide administrative
> credentials, otherwise click Yes in the UAC box.
>
> When Regedit starts, navigate to HKEY_USERS and left click it.
>
> [image]
>
> Go to the menu and select File->Load Hive. For more information on
> loading Windows Registry hives;
> http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc732157.aspx.
>
> [image]
>
> Browse to the NTUSER.DAT file based on which Windows version you are
> using and Open it. You will have to have, ‘show hidden and system
> files’ enabled in the folder options control panel. For more
> information;
> http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows7/Show-hidden-files.
>
> [image]
>
> Give the hive a name, it does not matter what name you give it. Here I
> used Default Profile, but it could have been anything.
>
> [image]
>
> In Regedit, browse to HKEY_USERS->whatever hive name you gave. You now
> be able to edit the default user profile registry settings. Remember
> to back them up first before editing
>
> [image]
>
> When finished, go to the menu File->Unload Hive.
>
> [image]
>
> That’s it! Any settings you change in the loaded hive will be copied
> to every new user profile that is created on that machine.

Source [Tip 49: How Do You Set Default User Profile Registry Settings](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/chad/2012/04/25/tip-49-how-do-you-set-default-user-profile-registry-settings/)

---

#### So what is HKU.DEFAULT if it's not the default user?

It's actually the profile for the Local System account and is an alias for HKEY_USERS\S-1-5-18:

> Despite its name, the profile for the .Default user is not the default
> user profile. It's actually the profile for the Local System account
> and is an alias for HKEY_USERS\S-1-5-18. (S-1-5-18 is the security
> identifier for the Local System account.) Consequently, settings in
> HKEY_USERS.Default are used by programs and services that run as
> Local System. The most visible examples of programs that run as Local
> System are winlogon and logonui, the programs that display the
> interface for logging onto the system. Whatever color scheme and
> screen saver you choose for the Local System profile get used at the
> logon screen.

...

> The registry settings for new users do not come from the .Default
> user. Rather, they come from what I've started calling the "template
> user", which is kept† in the file C:\Documents and Settings\Default
> User\ntuser.dat. This hive is not loaded most of the time (since
> there's no reason to waste memory on something that is needed only
> rarely), so if you want to make a change to the template user, you'll
> have to load the hive manually.
>
> Mind you, messing with the template user hive directly is most likely
> not supported. The supported way of modifying the template user hive
> on Windows XP is to use the system preparation tool "SysPrep". Boot
> into factory mode, make your customizations to the current user, then
> reseal. The resealing process propagates the current user's settings
> to the template user (or, more specifically, the ones that can safely
> be propagated to the template user—you don't want to propagate things
> like encryption keys) before "resealing" the system for deployment.

Source [The .Default user is not the default user](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20070302-00/?p=27783)

Comment: Hmmm, I didn't realize that `SysPrep` does all the things for me. However when I set "Show This PC on desktop" in Control Panel (which actually sets `HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\HideDesktopIcons\NewStartPanel\{20D04FE0-3AEA-1069-A2D8-08002B30309D}` to `DWORD 0`) and then use SysPrep to seal it, the setting doesn't seem to be applied to new users when I later install that system with my tweaks.

Comment: @iBug Don't know anything about sysprep - I've never used it :(

Answer (score 0):

I like PowerShell to add some settings while imaging.

```
reg.exe load HKLM\DefaultUser C:\users\default\NTUSER.DAT
#Windows 11 - Hide weather widget
New-ItemProperty "HKLM:\DefaultUser\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Advanced" -Name "TaskbarDa" -PropertyType DWORD -Value 0 -Force
reg.exe /unload HKLM\DefaultUser
```