# Store windows 7 and 10 config for all users

Tags: windows, taskbar, default-settings, windows-tabletpc

I'm trying to configure Windows 7 and 10 for all users, unfortunately by default settings are stored only on admin account, on which it was configured. For example I'm trying to turn off "Press and hold" in "tabletpc.cpl" settings or turn of "Show taskbar on all displays" in taskbar options.

Is there any way to store these settings for all users, which are logging in on this machine?

Comment: Use group policies. Either from the domain or local group policies (gpedit.msc)

Comment: I'm found how to set up "Show taskbar on all displays" in gpedit, but have no idea how to change options in "tabletpc.cpl" via gpedit. Do you know how it can be done?

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 ways to apply settings to all users:

1. Use GPO that will apply at every user logon (if you have ADC server)
2. Configure Default user profile.

You can setup the profile files themselves at C:\Users\Default 
e.g. put shortcuts for all users to *C:\Users\Default\Desktop*
etc.

All the other user settings need to be configured using registry keys. You need to set desired registry keys in the default user profile.
Default user profile registry hive is stored in **C:\Users\Default\NTUSER.DAT** file.

You may also want to put a batch *logon script* that will run at first logon of every user and would set the desired settings.
For this you need to put the cmd script on the drive available for the user accounts and set a path to it in the registry in the default profile.

If you loaded Default profile to HKLM\temp folder, you need to navigate to

```
HKLM\temp\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\RunOnce
```

in the right pane of this hive add a new REG_SZ record with any name and put path to cmd script as a value.

To change default settings for a new user on a workstation follow this [answer](https://superuser.com/questions/1285378/apply-registry-tweak-to-newly-created-users).

You may also want to look at [mandatory roaming user profiles](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/client-management/mandatory-user-profile).