# In Windows 10 v1903 is there a way to make the light taskbar and start menu default for new users

Tags: windows-10, colors

In Windows 10 v1903 is there a way to make the light taskbar and start menu default for new users, with a registry key or a group policy setting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure is.
Registry Key for color personalization can be found here: `HKCU\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Themes\Personalize`

You can add key for `SystemUsesLightTheme` reg_dword and give it a value of 1.

Comment: Does this work for both the light app theme as well as the new light taskbar and start menu option included with the May 2019 feature update?

Comment: I haven't pushed the update to my environment yet - but you could make the change, then hit that hive to see what keys it drops in there. That hive should still contain all of the theme keys once they are set

Comment: Nice.  Yeah it was there, just "SystemUsesLightTheme" instead of "AppsUseLightTheme"

Comment: @Willdorf cool, edited to reflect the correct key

Comment: combined with this: https://superuser.com/questions/1285378/apply-registry-tweak-to-newly-created-users we have a solution